# To determine the time of the resource pool storing pallets

Tags: anylogic

I would like to determine the time my forklifts are storing the pallets into my pallet rack. So for example the overall storing time for 50 pallets should last 30 minutes. Currently I define the overall storing time trough the speed of the forklifts but it is to inaccurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible as you cannot predict the path they will take to store something (else you could work out the speed from your required time).

PS: As mentioned before, it appears you are modelling things backwards: you take observed data and try to push it into a model. But simulation works the other way around: Take real-world performance (speed of your forklifts) and learn the performance of the system as an output.

Comment: @JackSock glad the answer was helpful. Please upvote this answer as “useful” (up-arrow next to the answer) to help other users find it in the future as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote for more info on how SOF works :)